Earliest Date as "Having" Condition
I have a two-pronged question: I want to search Contacts whose first contribution is within a date range, so I have grouped by Contact ID and included Contributions.
Min of Contribution Date does actually give the first date in the output, but when I try to use it as a Having condition, I am getting only a text field rather than a date field, and can't make sense of what comparison I am doing.
The second issue (down the line) is that really I'd want to use a relative date, ie first contribution date is within so many months of today.
The latter I realise may not be possible, but I feel that the first ought to work.

What version of CiviCRM is this? I feel like I read a bug report about this recently.

Thanks; just catching up.  But the version is 5.65.2 on WordPress.

Does the problem occur on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org?  If not, you can resolve it with an upgrade.  Though you should upgrade anyway, that version of CiviCRM is insecure!

I am just going out but I will try asap.  Thank you

I can't seem to do anything in the sandbox at all. It is displaying just as text with no menu.

How can SearchKit be accessed in the sandbox? I see only a very limited range of functions.

yep that demo site seems a bit borked - you can try https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ as SK features should be independent of CMS

This took a bit of working out, but I got there in the end.  Unforch, the having condition for min of contribution date still gives a text field. I don't know what format it's expecting, but If I put greater than anything I get all dates and if I put less than anything I get no dates.
